# Find current Windows BCD Store file path

Tags: windows, winapi, registry

I need to get the currently Windows using BCD Store file path.

I know the current BCD Store registry is loaded under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\BCD00000000 but I couldn't find any WinAPI to get the file path of a loaded key.

Usually the volume containing the BCD file is not mounted so I also finding an API that results the disk index and partition index of the BCD file.

Comment: What is the file path of the loaded key? Is it the path to the disk or the path to the registry?

Comment: I mean the BCD file path. BCD file type is a registry file.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the tag [tag:bcd].

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc721886(v=ws.10)):

> Where is the BCD file located in the registry?
>
> - BIOS-based operating
>   systems. The BCD registry file is located in the \Boot\Bcd directory
>   of the active partition.
> - EFI–based operating systems. The BCD registry file is located on the
>   EFI system partition.

I would not *think* that there is no (public) API to get that information programmatically, much less use that information for anything useful. (this part would be a comment: you might want to explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve)

Comment: I'm trying to distinguish BCD files that exist on multiple partitions and to delete partitions not being currently used.